# Caps lock option for input switch is absent

Tags: settings, bug, high-sierra

I have a MacBook Air 11" and a MacBook Air 13": the 11" is lot older than the 13". Although High Sierra is installed on both MacBooks, on the 13", I can't find caps lock option in Settings-> Keyboard-> Input Sources, but on the 11" it is present. I even don't know what to search for: both laptops have the latest update installed from the App Store.

[image]

Comment: It would be better to show us a picture of the one where you have the problem instead of the one where you do not.

Answer (score 1):

+Go to Apple > About this Mac and double check that the machine is actually running 10.13 and not 10.12 (caps lock does not work for Russian in 10.12).

+Add an Arabic keyboard to your input sources list and restart.

+Do a [safe boot](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH25617)

+Set up a new user account and see if you have the same problem when logged into that.